# How to implement a C function that will not proceed with it's operations if it is called more than 100 times per second?

Tags: c

I need to implement a function which should not proceed it's operations if it is called more than 100 times per a sec. Any suggestions how can I write this function in C?

Comment: Instead of describing what you're trying to do, describe [what problem you're trying to solve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Sure you can. All you need is `time`, `gmtime`, and some static storage to keep track of the "current second" and the number of calls made during it.

Comment: On which operating system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
uint64_t timedfun(uint64_t a, uint64_t b)       //dummy arguments, replace with yours
{
  static time_t lastt;                          //might want to use _Thread_local
  static uint_fast8_t count;                    //might want to use _Thread_local
  time_t currt = time(NULL);
  if (lastt != currt)
    {
      lastt = currt;
      count = 0;
    }
  if (++count > 100)
    {
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);            //You didn't specify what to do when it's called more than 100 times...
    }
  return a+b;                        //dummy result, replace with your function
}
```

As nos touched upon thread-safety in his answer, I've added some comments. The comments show where an applicable storage/lifetime specifier should go to ensure thread-safety (this will allow up to 100 calls to this function **per thread**). Otherwise this limit would be **shared over all threads**, and prone to race-conditions. In that case, you might need a mutex too.
Edit for non-POSIX systems, pure C-compliance (kudos to chux's comment):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
uint64_t timedfun(uint64_t a, uint64_t b)       //dummy arguments, replace with yours
{
  static time_t lastt;                          //might want to use _Thread_local
  static uint_fast8_t count;                    //might want to use _Thread_local
  time_t currt = time(NULL);
  if (difftime(lastt, currt) >= 1.0)            //uses floating-point numbers, use for non-POSIX systems
    {
      lastt = currt;
      count = 0;
    }
  if (++count > 100)
    {
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);            //You didn't specify what to do when it's called more than 100 times...
    }
  return a+b;                        //dummy result, replace with your function
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the simple answer.

Comment: In practice this works, but `time_t` is permitted to be in units other than seconds, e.g. to be higher resolution. So to be fully correct, you would need to convert the `time_t` to `struct tm` and compare it that way.

Comment: On POSIX, `time()` returns seconds (or, to be precise, something close to seconds) since the Unix-Epoch.

Comment: @R.. and OP, using `difftime()` would simplify portability.

Comment: @chux: Sure, that would work. It's a bit ugly in my opinion, since it uses a `double`, and so now you're involving the FPU in this calculation for no good reason. Seems like a waste to me.

Comment: How would you recommend to make this solution portable?

Comment: @chux: Oh, I'm not saying that this isn't the easiest portable solution. I'm just saying it's a shame it *is*. If everyone was POSIX-compliant (Or the C standard was more specific), we could avoid this kludge.

Comment: @R.. 2 approaches 1) This answer using 1 sample and then see if 100 occur within 1 sec.  Something like the 2nd solution posted here other than I'd use `if (difftime(lastt, currt) >= 1.0)` as `difftime ()` may have finer than 1.0 second resolution.  The 2nd approach follows John's idea of 100 buckets then checking if the 100th previous invocation for <= 1.0 seconds ago.  This 2nd approach would detect a burst of say 60 calls right before a 1 second tick and a burst of 60 calls right after the tick.

Answer (score 3):

Add:

```
usleep(10000);
```

**:)**

Short of that you'll need to allocate storage to hold the times of the last 100 invocations, and keep track of those in a rotating fashion.  This seems silly, but perhaps there might in some dark corner of the universe be a reasonable reason to do this.

Comment: No, you just need the time of the last invocation, rounded to 1-second resolution.

Comment: Huh, if the last invocation is the same second as the current invocation, how do I know how many there have been in the current second?  Could be just these two, could be billions.

Comment: Actually, a time-stamp AND a counter should be sufficient then.  As long as it is 100 in any given second on the clock, not worrying about 100 which might span a particular second to the next second on the clock.

Comment: Yes, sorry; but "just" I meant that you don't need a full record of the last 100 invocations, not that you don't need any additional information (the counter).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a token bucket principle to rate limit your function.

First some common stuff:

```
struct RateLimit {
    //how many tickets we want
    long tickets;
    //per this period of time
    long period;

    //internal fields:

    //money we have to "buy" tickets
    long funds;
    //time of the previos period
    long last_refill_ts;
};

#define RATELIMIT_INITIALIZER(tickets, period)\
{ tickets, period, 0, -period}

//current_ts must be in the unit of r->period
static void ratelimit_refill(struct RateLimit *r, long current_ts)
{

    long diff_period;
    //Find elapsed time
    diff_period = current_ts - r->last_refill_ts;

    if (diff_period > r->period) {
        //help prevent overflow when calculating available tickets below
        diff_period = r->period;
    } else if (diff_period < 0) {
        //time went backwards, skip this round
        diff_period = 0;
    }

    //Calculate the cost of tickets that became available 
    r->funds += diff_period * r->tickets;

    //throttle handing out tickets
    if (r->funds > r->period * r->tickets) {
        r->funds = r->period * r->tickets;
    }

    //save this period. 
    r->last_refill_ts = current_ts;
}

int ratelimit_allow(struct RateLimit *r, long current_ts)
{
    int allowed;

    if (r->funds < r->period) { //not enough funds

        ratelimit_refill(r, current_ts);

        //as we keep track of the last timestamp of refilling
        //We don't need to refill when there is enough funds
    }

    //If we have enough to buy atleast one ticket, we can allow 
    if (r->funds >=  r->period) {
        r->funds -= r->period;
        allowed = 1;
    } else {
        //not enough to buy a ticket
        allowed = 0;
    }

    return allowed;
}
```

Then you'd use this in your function that you want to rate limit:

```
void my_function(void)
{   //limit to 100/sec
    static struct RateLimit rl = RATELIMIT_INITIALIZER(100, 1); 
    if (!ratelimit_allow(&rl, time(NULL))) {
         abort(); //or less drastic measures
    }
    //your actual code here
}
```

Note - this function is not thread safe, you'd have to provide a mutex or similar around the ratelimit_allow() to make it thread safe too.